# R function find the percentage of outliers in a column?

Tags: r, function, outliers

I need to create a function that calculates the percentage of outlier in a data frame column. For outlier I mean any data point more than 3 standard deviation from the mean.

I looked at the package [outlier](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf) but this didn't sort me out since all functions seem to be oriented at finding outliers and not at counting them.

Is there a function I can use for it?

Comment: If you notice, everyone here had to create an example data set on their own in order to answer your question. Couldn't you be bothered to make one on your own? And maybe provide a desired output too? Not to mention that I don't see *anything* that you tried yourself except Googling "a package for detecting outliers r". If no one wrote it, you could at least try something on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this function is what you need:

```
outliersper <- function(x){
  length(which(x >  mean(x) + 3 * sd(x) | x < mean(x) - 3 * sd(x))  ) / length(x)
}
```

Example data

```
#3 outliers here
df <- data.frame(col= c(1000,1000,1000,runif(100)))

#function
> outliersper(df$col)
[1] 0.02912621
```

Validation

```
> length(which(df$col > (3 * sd(df$col))))
[1] 3
> 3/length(df$col)
[1] 0.02912621
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland. Valid comment as usual. I had missed this.

Comment: You were just unlucky that `mean(x > 1)` gives exactly the same result in your test case.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, assuming `x` is a column in your data frame?

```
set.seed(321)
x <- rnorm(10000)
x[x > mean(x) + 3*sd(x) | x < mean(x) - 3*sd(x)]
 [1]  3.135843 -3.006514  3.227549 -3.255502  3.065514  3.159309 -3.171849
 [8]  3.215432  3.120442  3.352662  3.574360  3.424063  3.126673 -3.024961
[15] -3.153842 -3.263268 -3.032526  3.179344 -3.605372
```

To get percentage of outliers

```
outli <- x[x > mean(x) + 3*sd(x) | x < mean(x) - 3*sd(x)]
length(outli) / length(x)
[1] 0.0019
```

And to make this a funciton

```
find_outlier <- function(x, num=3) {
  mean(x > mean(x) + num*sd(x) | x < mean(x) - num*sd(x))
}


find_outlier(x)
[1] 0.0019
```

Comment: `mean(insert_logical_vector_here)` gives you the percentage of TRUE values.  You can avoid using `length` here.

Comment: @Dason.   Yes, that's better.  I have edited the function.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(54)
dat = as.data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(10000)))

set.seed(321)
dat$ExtraCol <- rnorm(10000)

# Number of SDs to be considered an outlier
n=3
```

In the code below, the `.` is a "pronoun" meaning "the current column of the data frame `dat`".

```
# Percent outliers in every column
dat %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(. > mean(.) + n*sd(.) | . < mean(.) - n*sd(.))/n()))

      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 ExtraCol
1 0.0031 0.0039 0.0024 0.0028 0.0022   0.0019
```

There are also a number of ways to select specific columns.

```
# Columns 1, 3, and 6
dat %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(. > mean(.) + n*sd(.) | . < mean(.) - n*sd(.))/n()), 
                 c(1,3,6))

      V1     V3 ExtraCol
1 0.0031 0.0024   0.0019

# Columns whose name includes "Extra"
dat %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(. > mean(.) + n*sd(.) | . < mean(.) - n*sd(.))/n()), 
                 matches("Extra"))

  ExtraCol
1   0.0019

# Select only numeric columns
dat$Letters = sample(LETTERS, 10000, replace=TRUE)

dat %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(. > mean(.) + n*sd(.) | . < mean(.) - n*sd(.))/n()),
                 which(sapply(., is.numeric)))

      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 ExtraCol
1 0.0031 0.0039 0.0024 0.0028 0.0022   0.0019
```

Comment: I got error: `summarise_each()` is deprecated in dplyr. Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
To map `funs` over a selection of variables, use `summarise_at()`